# python Multiprocessing Pool issue running only on single core

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code that uses a function to do some heavy numerical simulations.

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# ~ CALL THE MULTIPROCESSING ROUTINES ~
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
p = Pool(processes=20) # by default will use 24 processors

p.map(FunctionName, List_NumberOfFiles)
p.close()
p.join()
```

The program start well and solves as shown in the photo below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od52k.png)

after few minutes it ends up not fully utilising the 20 cores as shown in the figure below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K099j.png)

if someone had a similar issue i would appreciate if you could share some thoughts as to how i can resolve this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Almost impossible to say what's going on without a view on the code for *FunctionName*

Comment: Passing `processes=20` will not automatically use 20 cores. It depends on what is getting executed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely expect to be able to see what you show in the second image. You first must understand how the multiprocessing pool works:

There are `N` elements (and thus `N` tasks to be submitted) in `List_NumberOfFiles` that will be placed on a single task queue in chunks that will be computed based on the size of the pool (20) and `N` since you did not explicitly specify the *chunksize* argument on your call to `map`. Each process in the pool when idle will pool from the task queue the next "chunk" of tasks from the queue and execute those tasks until completion and then get the next chunk until there are no more chunks on the queue left. It would be a miracle if all 20 processes completed executing their final chunk at the same time. Instead, I would expect to see a single final process left executing the last final chunk.

As an example, supposed there were 302 elements in `List_NumberOfFiles` (`N` = 300). The computed *chunksize* value would be 4. That would produce 75 chunks of size 4 with one chunk of size 2. Even assuming each task took approximately the same amount of time to process, after the 20 processes completed their first 3 chunks, that would leave 15 full-sized chunks and one small chunk left. These 16 chunks would be grabbed by 16 of the processes and 4 processes would now be permanently idle. The process that grabbed the small chunk (that is, the one with only 2 tasks) will soon go permanently idle. The remaining 15 processes will go permanently idle as they complete the processing of their full-sized chunks. The most likely scenario is that they will all end at different times.

Now imagine that you have submitted 20 tasks (`List_NumberOfFiles` as 20 elements). The *chunksize* computed will be 1, which makes the analysis far simpler. Each process in the pool only has one task to process before it becomes permanently idle. What if one of these tasks just happens to take  quite a bit longer to process than the others? The longer it takes then the longer you will see all the processes idle except for one.